# JRuby, Sinatra, Warbler app - HTTP PATCH request fails with 501 error

Tags: sinatra, jruby, warbler, http-patch

I've created a simple web service using JRuby 1.7.4, Sinatra 1.4.4 and Rack 1.5.2. This web service responds to GET, POST, PATCH and DELETE requests with a simple message "Hello world using [request-type]".

I started Rack and tested all the request types. All four worked.

I used Warbler to create a war file of the application and deployed it to Tomcat 7.0.47. When I tested with Tomcat PATCH failed with a "HTTP Status 501 - Method PATCH is not is not implemented by this servlet for this URI". (Yes, 'is not' is repeated. But this is the response I get from Tomcat.) GET, POST and DELETE worked fine.

I then tried using Jetty 9.1.0. Same result. GET, POST and DELETE work but PATCH fails.

Why are PATCH requests failing and how do I get them to work with this set up?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/index.html) HttpServlet can handle only GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests

> public abstract class HttpServlet
> extends GenericServlet
>
> Provides an abstract class to be subclassed to create an HTTP servlet
> suitable for a Web site. A subclass of HttpServlet must override at
> least one method, usually one of these:
>
> doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests doPost, for HTTP POST
> requests doPut, for HTTP PUT requests doDelete, for HTTP DELETE
> requests

But you can find this useful:

> If you use an HTTP library that doesn't allow overriding or setting an
> arbitrary HTTP method name, you can send a POST request and provide an
> override to the HTTP method via the query string parameter
> _HttpMethod.

For example, to update an Account, this will work with an actual POST request:

```
.../services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Account/0016000000eEhmxAAC?_HttpMethod=PATCH
```

Comment: A similar suggestion was made a friend. However, I don't control the incoming requests and can't modify them.